# How to get the value of the current swap directory in vimscript?

Tags: vim

You can set a list of directories for vim to use for the swapfile (with it defaulting to the first one it can find) with:

```
set directory=~/tmp,~/var/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
```

I want to know which directory vim has chosen for its swapfile so I can stick some temp data in there.

Parsing `&directory` and looping through the values seems like a waste when vim should have already figured that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:swapname` command will tell you which swapfile is used for the current buffer. You need to use `:redir => varname` to capture the output and store it in a variable.

Comment: That was the best I had come up with as well. and it will (of course) fail if noswapfile so parsing &directory is going to be better.

Comment: It then says `No swap file`, you can check for `'noswapfile'` before, anyway, so I don't see how parsing `'directory'` is better. Especially because the swap extension is not necessarily `.swp`; it could also be `.swo`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "used" directory is not saved somewhere by vim, like a variable or something. It could be different from buffer to buffer. (from file to file).

e.g.

you have a non-root user. say `kent`,  his directory setting is:

```
set directory=.,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
```

now kent opens  `/etc/host.conf` in his vim, and editing. the first `.(dot)` means current dir. obviously kent cannot write file to `/etc`, so take the 2nd `~/tmp`, but kent doesn't have `tmp` under his home, so next, `/var/tmp` is used.

if kent opens a file under his HOME, or under `/tmp`, for example, the `.(dot)` would be used. And note that the `dot` for different files are different.

kent can open many files in buffers, so it is hard to say, which dir would be used for swap files.

so the swapfile - dir is not fixed to a directory. you should check it based on the buffer/file.

Comment: This is probably the case, but obviously the swapname is a per-buffer value, so it seems like `swapdir` (or something) should also be available. having to either parse swapname or `&directory` seems silly.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this often, I suggest to write a function:

```
function! SwapDirectoryForCurrentFile()
    redir => filename
    silent! swapname
    redir end
    return fnamemodify(filename, ":h")
endfunction
```